# get the selected elements from a ListBox(with multipleselect) which is inside a FormView Template

Tags: asp.net

So I have a **FormView**. Inside the **InsertTemplate** I have a *ListBox*

```
<asp:ListBox ID="AppsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
             DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Id") %>'
             AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>`
```

In my **ObjectDataSource** I only get the first selection (If I have two or three selected elements, only the id of the first one is submitted).

```
public void InsertOperator(string companyName, string address, string phoneNumber, string email, 
                           string NrPoints, string perimeterPointsList,object Id)
```

I actualy put the "object" type for parameter Id (coming from the ListBox) to see what type is passed to the method. It is a string. So how can I make it be the list/array of all selected Ids, not just the first selected?

Comment: I am not sure why you can't just do AppsList.SelectedItems to grab the list of ALL SelectedItems in the ListBox. I don't follow the purpose of the `InsertOperator` method

Comment: Because AppsList is inside a InsertTemplate of a FormView, and it's binded to the current objectSource of the FormView